# Elementary Jacobian

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I know it's easy, and I'm sure somewhere someone already asked or it, but I couldn't find it. I have the following function $F:\mathbb{R}^{3}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$
Could you tell me how to calculate the Jacobian Matrix?
\begin{equation}
F(r,\:\theta,\:\phi)=\left(r\:\sin\theta\cos\phi,\: r\:\sin\theta\sin\phi,\; r\:\cos\theta\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_3:_spherical-Cartesian_transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it's an example it's in any textbook
$$
J=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin\theta\cos\phi & r\:\cos\theta\cos\phi & -r\:\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
\sin\theta\sin\phi & r\:\cos\theta\sin\phi & r\:\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
\cos\theta & -r\:\sin\theta & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: The order of the rows is fixed?